# phpfmt formatter in VSC puts type before access-modifiers in class members declarations

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am using [phpfmt](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt) in Visual Studio Code but unfortunetly it transforms this:

```php
class Foo
{
    public string $bar;
}
```

to his:

```php
class Foo
{
    stringpublic $bar;
}
```

What am I doing wrong or how to correct it?
I will be grateful for any hint

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know what the problem is. phpfmt (last released 2018) is too old to support class property type declarations introduced in php 7.4 in 2019.

Comment: How did you resolve this?